# How Can i save .xls file to a certain location without using jiterbit

Tags: visualforce

How Can i save .xls file to a certain location/server/shared location without  using jiterbit

Comment: Where you need to save the xls ? Manually? Apex ? Batch ? could you give us more information ?

Comment: can you pls be more specific? are you using jitterbit for data integration between sfdc and external interface?

Comment: Hi i need to save my xls file in a local server

Comment: i assume your xls files are exists as an attachment in salesforce and you want to save it to a server. 1. you can write an console app using java or C# and call the salesforce webservices. 2. And query the object where your attachment (xls) are attached to. 3. You need to use file system classes in your c# or java app because the attachment in salesforce are in bytes. Use file operation to read the bytes from the attachment object and convert or cast to appropriate file type in your case it is .xls. .Note: you can schedule your console app in the scheduler so that it runs at certain frequency